# CSS div height not adjusting

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display a 100% height div within my page:
https://jsfiddle.net/pkggv96j/

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 mapContainer">
                <div class="GISMap" v-el:map>test</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 incidentContainer">
                <div class="incidentForm">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

// --Page Content
#page-content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.row .mapContainer {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.GISMap {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.incidentForm {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.row .incidentContainer {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

But `row` only has a height of 20pt and does not scale up to 100%. Did I miss an encompassing element to be set to height 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}

.row, .container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}

.row .mapContainer {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.GISMap {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.incidentForm {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.row .incidentContainer {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 mapContainer">
                <div class="GISMap" v-el:map>test</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 incidentContainer">
                <div class="incidentForm">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sesc360 For every child which has percent as height, their parent need a height as well, all the way to the body if necessary.

Comment: so .row, .container-fluid means, that the class .row as well as .container-fluid should have a height of 100% right?

Comment: can I streamline the CSS a bit more when it comes to the 100% height for parents? Like including more than these 2 elements separated via comma?

Comment: @sesc360 Yes, you can

Comment: I would have one more issue... The map is overflowing the row... I adjusted the question. How do I know where to look into.. I really struggle debugging these layout issues.

Comment: @sesc360 I will be happy to help, but that is a completely new question, so please roll back your edit and ask a new with your new requirements.